# Serializing IronPython Objects Which Inherit From CLR Types

Tags: c#, python, serialization, ironpython, pickle

This may be a bit of a weird question, but is there any reliable way to serialize IronPython objects whose classes extend CLR types?

For instance:

```
class Foo(System.Collections.Generic.List[str]):
    def Test(self):
        print "test!"
```

`System.Collections.Generic.List<string>` is serializable with Pickle, as it implements the `ISerializable` interface, but emitted subclasses of serializable CLR types seem to not work, and i get `ImportError: No module named Generic in mscorlib, Version=4` when running `pickle.dumps(Foo())`.

Additionally, running the usual `Formatter.Serialize(stream, object)` gives me:

```
SystemError: Type 'IronPython.NewTypes.System.Collections.Generic.List`1_4$4' in Assembly Snippets.scripting, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.
```

How can I implement serialization of IronPython objects when running in an embedded C# environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from [**clrtype** metaclasses](https://web.archive.org/web/20090728005603/http://devhawk.net/CommentView,guid,2a805bcd-c55b-4251-9149-935b06a019ac.aspx)

> IronPython doesn’t support Reflection
>   based APIs or custom attributes today
>   because IronPython doesn’t emit a
>   custom CLR types for every Python
>   class. Instead, it typically shares a
>   single CLR type across many Python
>   classes. For example, all three of
>   these Python classes share a single
>   underlying CLR type.

```
class shop(object):
  pass 

class cheese_shop(shop):
  def have_cheese(self, cheese_type):
    return False

class argument_clinic(object):
  def is_right_room(self, room=12):
    return "I've told you once"

import clr
print clr.GetClrType(shop).FullName
print clr.GetClrType(cheese_shop).FullName
print clr.GetClrType(argument_clinic).FullName
```

> Even though cheese_shop inherits from
>   shop and argument_clinic inherits from
>   object, all three classes share the
>   same underlying CLR type

I haven't tried, but maybe you can solve this issue with manual serialization via [serialization surrogates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializationsurrogate.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is what you are after, but you could consider the python version of protobuf ([here](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/tutorials.html))? I haven't tested it specifically on ironpython, mind. This has the added advantage that there are also C# implementations that may help, while keeping it platform independent. When possible I *want* to get protobuf-net to support DLR types, but that is a big job.

As a side note, personally I'd recommend having a dedicated DTO type rather than trying to extend the inbuilt types.

Comment: I'm simply using `System.Collections.Generic<string>` as an example -- I have my own CLR types in my assembly which I have implemented `ISerializable` for and that I want to serialize.